# Php Count duplicate numbers in a string and based on the value add in another string

Tags: php, string, count, duplicates

I have two strings:

string1 = "1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1"; 
string2 = "124200,23287.5,12420,31050,24840,43470,12420,6210,3105,3105"

both having equal numbers of values i.e., in above case is 10(count).

Now based on the string1 value I want to add string2 values.
Example: String1 first value is 1 so take string2 first value now whenever in the string1 the value gets repeated it should add up in string2.

So String1 1st value = 1
var total = 124200

Now String1 2nd value = 1
var total = 124200+23287.5

Now String1 3rd value = 1
var total = 124200+23287.5+12420

Here as the value in the string1 changed take another total variable and add to that
Now String1 4th value = 2
var total2 = 31050

Now string1 5th value = 2
var total2 = 31050+24840

Now string1 6th value = 2
var total2 = 31050+24840+43470

Now string1 7th value = 2
var total2 = 31050+24840+43470+12420

Here once again the value is 1 so it should add up to the total variable and not in total2
Now string1 8th value = 1
var total = 124200+23287.5+12420+6210

Now string1 9th value = 2
var total2 = 31050+24840+43470+12420+3105

Now string1 10th value = 1
var total = 124200+23287.5+12420+6210+3105

Result:
total = 169222.5
total2 = 114885

here there are only 2 unique values but it can be all different values or no different values.

NOTE:  let me try to make it more clear: String1 and String2 will always have same length i.e, 4 numbers in string1 then 4 in the string2. That mean the sum variables will also be 4. Now the numbers in string1 are what is important to us as whenever the number in string1 gets repeated we will add a number of string2 to the respective sum/total variable. at the end, all sum variable should show the final (added) result.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Please reformat your question to make it more clear and more understandable. Write some code and share it with us. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: Share the code and if possible make your question short and simple

Comment: @Marten let me try to make it more clear:
String1 and String2 will always have same length i.e, 4 numbers in string1 then 4 in the string2. That mean the sum variables will also be 4.

Now the numbers in string1 is what is important to us as whenever the number in string1 gets repeated we will add a number of string2 to the respective sum/total variable. at the end all sum variable should show the final (added) result.

Please do let me know if you still feels something is unclear.

Comment: @Hitesh, you should edit your question instead of commenting ;)

Comment: I'm sure this problem has a specific name, I just don't remember it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a strategy:

```
<?php
$str1 = "1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1"; 
$str2 = "124200,23287.5,12420,31050,24840,43470,12420,6210,3105,3105";
$array1 = explode(",",$str1);
$array2 = explode(",", $str2);
$cumulateGroups = [];
foreach ($array1 as $index => $groupIndex) {
   $cumulateGroups[$groupIndex] = isset($cumulateGroups[$groupIndex])?$cumulateGroups[$groupIndex]:[];
   $cumulateGroups[$groupIndex][] = $array2[$index];
}
print_r(array_map('array_sum',$cumulateGroups));
```

Check it out at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71bb2cd6d17f4086e8c9f9676aac4afe31df73ba

Edited: Removed junk.

Comment: It Works, but how do I access the values like:
Array
(
    [1] => 169222.5
    [2] => 114885
)

Comment: `$result = array_map('array_sum',$cumulateGroups);` (instead of the `print_r`) Then you can access `$result[1]` or `$result[2]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way here is my code

```
    $string1 = "1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1"; 
    $arr1 = array();
    $string2     = "124200,23287.5,12420,31050,24840,43470,12420,6210,3105,3105";
    $arr2 = array();

    $string1_arr = explode(',', $string1);
    $string2_arr = explode(',', $string2);


    $previous_value = '1';

    foreach ($string1_arr as $key => $value) 
    {

        if($value == $previous_value)
        {
            array_push($arr1, $string2_arr[$key]);
            $previous_value = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($arr2, $string2_arr[$key]);

        }
    }
    $total = array_sum($arr1);
    $total2 = array_sum($arr2);
```

Comment: Appreciate the efforts, but What if String1 = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" and string2 unchanged in this case it should have 10 total vairable and each one showing single value of string2 as total i guess the above code won't work there as the arr1 and arr2 are the static variable

Answer (score 0):

store values in array. compare using if statement. something like this

if($string[0]==$string[1]){ $total=$string2[0]+$string2[1];

}else{ $total=$string2[0]; } echo $total; ?>

Comment: do it same for all

Comment: can't do it that way as the length of the numbers in string is dynamic but same for both like it could be string1 = "3,7" and string2 = "1200,456" the count will always remains same but the length may differ so i need a dynamic solution. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code

```
1) convert both strings to arrays(arr1,arr2) using explode
2) create new associative array output{key=>value}
3) foreach on arr1, do output['value of arr1']+=value of arr'2'
4) output will be your desired result
```